# Workrave applet blank in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: workrave

I installed Workrave, the RSI prevention application, on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 (`apt-get install workrave`) and the applet that shows up in the system tray is blank. In Ubuntu 15.10 I saw timers in this area.

[image: Workrave tray applet blank]

Can anybody suggest how to get the applet to correctly display?

Comment: I can't even get the blank indicator displayed on 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the PPA `ppa:rob-caelers/workrave`, install `workrave-data` and `workrave-unity` and restart Unity.

Comment: there is no package named `workrave-unity`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Anna! Please see my update regarding the PPA.

Comment: Thank you! Note that the `workrave-data` package must be installed beforehand or this will cause `workrave-unity` to crash when trying to install it, at least as per my experience

Comment: Sadly uninstalling the package and reinstalling from the PPA doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Any error messages? What packages do you have installed now?

Comment: monkbroc said: "Sadly uninstalling the package and reinstalling from the PPA doesn't solve the issue." - same here.  I installed it with aptitude (with no errors) because synaptic was giving an error (multiline error, I only saved the first line: "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."). According to synaptic I now have the following packages installed: `workrave`, `workrave-data` and `workrave-unity`. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah! I restarted unity with `unity --replace`, then started workrave and it did show the applet in the top bar. @monkbroc: you can try that.

Comment: However, the systray icon of workrave randomly disappears, still. One can click its space to access its menu, but the icon is not visible.

Comment: Last time I tried it I couldn't get the PPA to work. Perhaps I still had a different package source for Workrave on my system. I tried again today because of Stefan's comments and now the applet shows up!

Comment: It's doesn't solve the problem on Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Thank you so much! For 16.04, the tray was not there AT ALL and THAT is a problem. Your solution worked like a charm. And maybe the sheep picture is not always seen but at least I can access the program. I am also grateful to the authors and the people who repaired Workrave for Ubuntu. The program is invaluable for me -- having hard times -- the veins in my eyes are always red now. The program + Redshift app will help me, I hope. THANK YOU AGAIN!